Is it possible to create a Molecular orbital diagram of Hydrogen Cyanide
I understand Molecular orbital diagrams of polyatomic molecules however I was wondering how would you do a molecular diagram for a molecule that has more than two types of atoms - my question specifically about hydrogen cyanide. In this case, we still have a central atom but the peripheral atoms are different. I was wondering whether you could still create SALCs with the peripheral atoms or whether it is even possible to do a molecular orbital diagram for this instance or whether it would break down.
